# Simple mysql query optimization on big tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a simple query, which takes 2.5 seconds to evaluate. I want to optimize it, but i haven't any idea how to do that. Can anyone advise how can it be optimized?
Logic is next: count all clicks grouped by referrer for specified campaign.
There "explain" of mysql query below. Tables clicks and users have many rows.

```
mysql> explain select count(*) as amount,ac.referrer from clicks ac
    ->         inner join users a on a.id = ac.user_id
    ->         where a.campaign_id = 26 group by ac.referrer
    ->         order by amount desc;

+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys     | key     | key_len | ref                    | rows    | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ac    | ALL    | ac_adv            | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                   | 1607031 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,advoc_cam | PRIMARY | 4       | mydb.ac.user_id        |       1 | Using where                     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, that did not provide the shemas, but there is no need now. Now i have full cover of columns with indexes as suggested in accepted answer.

That was right solution to add index (c.user_id, c.referrer). Other indexes already exist and make no sense. But now query completing in 0.2 sec instead of 2.5-3 sec before. Thanks!

Comment: Please show us table definitions!

Comment: Show us table structure please.
Try this: ALTER TABLE `clicks ` ADD INDEX `referrer` (`referrer`);

Comment: I don't really get it. Presumably you already have a compound PRIMARY KEY on (referrer,user_id), and users.id MUST already be a PK. So the only thing left is to add an index to campaign_id - but I doubt that that will make much difference. :-(

Comment: Composite indexes on table "users" doesn't make any changes. But on "clicks" they did. Of course, there is correct PK on all tables. Thanks to all, look for accepted solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I'd probably rewrite your query as:

```
  SELECT c.referrer,
         count(*) amount,
    FROM clicks c
    JOIN users u
      ON u.campaign_id = 26
     AND u.id = c.user_id
GROUP BY c.referrer
ORDER BY amount DESC
```

Just to be clear as to what is going on.

Your basic query is about as good as it is going to get so you'll need indexes to improve the performance.

For the JOIN to users, the primary key on `u.id` should be pretty good, but you may get better performance from a composite on `(u.campaign_id, u.id)`.

For the main table clicks you should try indexes on `c.user_id` and `c.referrer` and maybe the two possible composites `(c.user_id, c.referrer)` and `(c.referrer, c.user_id)`. Use the EXPLAIN plan to work out which are possible_keys and drop the ones that don't help.

You may have to hint at some indexes if the query doesn't use them but they show up in the possible_keys (you can only use one per table or join - one row of the plan).

With a composite on each table, where the two indexes cover all four referenced columns, e.g. `(u.campaign_id, u.id)` and `(c.user_id, c.referrer)` the query should be covered by the indexes and not need to access the table rows which should increase performance further.

Also bear in mind any new indexes will slow down DML actions (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) where they contain columns referenced by the index, so if you have a high write rate it may be better to take the hit on this query instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select count(a.user_id) as amount,ac.referrer 
from users a 
INNER JOIN clicks ac
on a.id = ac.user_id
where a.campaign_id = 26 
group by ac.referrer
order by amount desc;
```

Have a key on the users table with fields `(CAMPAIGN_ID, user_id)`

-> This will loop over the users table, and then add the clicks for each user found.

Answer (score -1):

```
mysql> explain select count(*) as amount,ac.referrer from clicks ac
->         inner join users a on a.id = ac.user_id AND a.campaign_id = 26 
->         group by ac.referrer
->         order by amount desc;
```

Change WHERE to AND in your query. May be it will be faster

Comment: This will have no affect, the optimiser will sort this out for you.